# Lógica de todas as misturas possíveis dos valores de um array de quantidade variável. PHP

Tags: php, array

Estou quebrando a cabeça para criar uma lógica que faça o seguinte:

Receba um array de N posições, dentro dessas posições definir todas as possibilidades possíveis sem repetir a key de uma posição.

Exemplo:
Array('A','B','C')

A
AB
ABC
AC
ACB
B
BA
BAC
BC
BCA
C
CA
CAB
CB
CBA

Exemplos da fórmula matemática

Quando existem 3 posições:
3+(3*2)+(3*2*1)
Quando existem 4 posições:
4+(4*3)+(4*3*2)+(4*3*2*1)

Comment: Acredito que poderia resolver isso utilizando `n` `for`, sendo `n` a quantidade de variáveis que irão ser utilizadas

Comment: Uma dúvida, você tem algum controle sobre a quantidade de variáveis que entram?

Comment: Sim, podem entrar de 1 a 10 valores e posso identificar quantos são.

Comment: ta dificil implementar isso... kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Se houver controle em cima da quantidade de variáveis que entram, você pode criar X estruturas `for`, sendo X a quantidade de variáveis do `array`, fazendo algo do tipo:

```
$arr = array("A","B","C");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    echo $arr[$i]."\n";
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr); $j++) {
        if ($i != $j) {
            echo $arr[$i].$arr[$j]."\n";
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($arr); $k++) {
                if ($i != $j && $i != $k && $j != $k) {
                    echo $arr[$i].$arr[$j].$arr[$k]."\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/8JeU1k)

É um processo mais manual, e exigiria uma quantidade maior de codificação, vou ver se consigo criar algo mais automatico.

Comment: Já pensei por esta possibilidade, mas acho que não fui claro no meu comentário anterior. Eu não defino quantos valores entram, somente sei quantos, a logica que busco deve comportar valores a serem definidos depois do recebimento dos valores do array. Estou tentando fazendo algo utilizando a recursividade nas chamadas para o for. Mas mesmo assim muito obrigado por esta resposta.

Comment: @paje Acredito que utilizando uma lógica meio hibrida usando o conceito de "binários" e potencia de um "número n" (tamanho do seu array), você consiga resolver seu problema, estou tentando elaborar aqui

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer com "conceito de binários". Estou tentando fazer quase do mesmo modo que você realizou manualmente, porém sem a necessidade de incluir mais chaves dentro do loop.